# How do I run a text file as a program with a single click?

Tags: shortcuts

New install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I set my text file to run as a program, and it runs just fine, the problem is that i have to right click and select run, instead of open. In the past I could just left click and it would run by default. Now it defaults to opening the text file, upon left click. Is there any way to get it to favor running, over opening? It used to do it in one click before.

Comment: More info needed. What do you mean, run a text file as a program? Are you referring to a desktop shortcut item, a script, or something else?

Comment: Well, for me, it's a line of text that runs a dosbox game. I'm talking about when you go into the properties of a text file, and select the box that says, "allow executing file as program"

Comment: While you cannot do this in GNOME, you can do this in other desktop interfaces like KDE or XFCE.

Answer (score 1):

Running any text file by just double-clicking on it is deprecated since several versions of the Gnome desktop. Double-clicking a file instead will always open the file in the application associated with the mimetype of that file. For an executable script, that will be the text editor.

This prevents that users inadvertently launch scripts or programs when double-clicking or hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the file manager. It still remains quite easy to run an executable from the right-click menu, but there at least there is some reflection and thinking: you deliberately are seeking to run a file.

It is far better practice to move your executable scripts to a directory in the search `PATH`, typically `~/.local/bin` (preferred) or `~/bin` (legacy). Then you launch your scripts by

- typing the file name inn the terminal or the Run prompt (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)
- From your application menu after you have created a `.desktop` launcher for it.

Comment: I never heard of the run command before. That's pretty nice to know. I generally don't run things with terminal because i can't close terminal without the program closing too. But i don't see typing things as a quicker alternative to just left clicking, or even right clicking and selecting an option.

Comment: Clicking on a `.desktop`  launcher is equally quick if there is a need to run something regularly. The idea is that regular users should not be exposed to an interface where they inadvertently could be running all kinds of things by double clicking on something. In contrast, users wanting to run "special things" know what they do and either will use "arrow up" in the terminal to rerun during testing, or install a .desktop launcher for a custom tool they want to run conveniently.

Comment: Okay, well, I haven't a clue, what you mean by "From your application menu after you have created a .desktop launcher for it." I don't know what a .desktop launcher is. I assume the Applications menu is the feature that seems to have replaced dash, but i could be wrong, for all i know, It doesn't specifically say applications menu anywhere.